# Rails: Ransack can't sort Date datatypes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, ransack

Why does Ransack fail to sort results when I want to sort by a Date attribute, but not when I try to sort by any other type of attribute?

Fails to sort by 'date_received":

```
@search = Student.search(params[:q])
@search.sorts = 'date_received' if @search.sorts.empty?
@students = @search.result.includes(:tests).to_a.uniq.
               paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: ENTRIES_PER_PAGE)
```

Succeeds to sort by 'last_name':

```
@search = Student.search(params[:q])
@search.sorts = 'last_name' if @search.sorts.empty?
@students = @search.result.includes(:tests).to_a.uniq.
               paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: ENTRIES_PER_PAGE)
```

By the way, here's what my student model looks like:

```
Student(id: integer, first_name: string, last_name: string, 
                                 major: string, date_received: date)
```

What gives?

Comment: what do you get when you run `@search.result.to_sql`. Also make sure the condition `if @search.sorts.empty?` is true.

Comment: When I run that, I get an error message: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `each' for "SELECT `students`.* FROM `students` ":String):

Comment: Also, I removed the condition if @search.sorts.empty? and it still didn't sort...

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out...I had date_received marked as UNRANSACKABLE because I didn't want users to be able to search by it.